# A PDF reader with internal links preview in a pop-up?

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-viewer, hyperlink

Like this :

[image]

There is Evince on Linux, but on Windows ?

Comment: I can't believe evince is (almost) the only pdf viewer having this feature. I just learned about it, and it's so insanely useful, it's a complete a game-changer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whom it may help :

I urge you to discover this jewel : https://sioyek.info/. Does all of the requested, and much more.